# Valid screen session names

Tags: gnu-screen

With GNU screen (version 4), why is it that the following runs perfectly fine:

```
$ screen -S some-name
```

But if I try having a slash (`/`) in the session name, it gives me an error about multiuser support.

```
$ screen -S some/name
Must run suid root for multiuser support.
```

If I try setting the session name from within the screen:

```
$ screen
C-a :sessionname some/name
```

I get the following error:

```
: bad session name 'some/name'
```

So apparently a `/` is invalid character for a session name. Looking at the [man page for screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html), I see nothing about invalid or reserved characters for `sessionname`:

> ‘-S sessionname’
>
> Set the name of the new session to sessionname. This option can be used to specify a meaningful name for the session in place of the default tty.host suffix. This name identifies the session for the screen -list and screen -r commands. This option is equivalent to the sessionname command (see Session Name).

> 8.5 Session Name
>   — Command: sessionname [name]
>
> (none)
>      Rename the current session. Note that for screen -list the name shows up with the process-id prepended. If the argument name is omitted, the name of this session is displayed.
>       Caution: The $STY environment variable still reflects the old name. This may result in confusion. The default is constructed from the tty and host names.

Also, unmatched `'` and `"` in the session name complain about unmatched quotes which seems to be about syntax. E.g., `:sessionname 'test"'` gives `test"` as the name. And `^A`, `^B`, etc. yield control characters.

What is the valid syntax or characters for a session name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The purpose of assigning a name to a screen session with `-S` is so you can operate on that session (for example with `screen -r ...`) by specifying its name.

Looking at the man page under the `-r` option:

> `-r [pid.tty.host]`
>   `-r sessionowner/[pid.tty.host]`
>      resumes  a detached screen session.  No other options (except com‐
>      binations with -d/-D) may be specified, though an optional  prefix
>      of  [pid.]tty.host  may  be needed to distinguish between multiple
>      detached screen sessions.  The second form is used to  connect  to 
>      another  user's  screen session which runs in multiuser mode. This
>      indicates that screen should look for sessions in  another  user's
>      directory. This requires setuid-root.

So a session name with a `/` character is interpreted as `owner/name`. (This could be documented better under the `-S` option.)

You *can* do

```
screen -S $USER/name
```

which is equivalent to:

```
screen -S name
```

In some quick experiments with screen version 4.01.00, I haven't found any other special characters that are prohibited in session names. All the following:

```
screen -S 'foo bar'
screen -S 'foo"bar'
screen -S "foo'bar"
screen -S 'foo\bar'
screen -S "foo'bar^Xbaz"
```

worked correctly for me.

In the last one, the `^X` was actually a literal <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd> character. `screen -ls` shows it literally; I had to do `screen -ls | cat -A` to see it. I was able to resume all these sessions by specifying their names:

```
screen -dr 'foo bar'
```

etc., and the value of `$STY` within each session was correct.

(I don't recommend using control characters, for what I hope are obvious reasons.)

Comment: Screen session names correspond directly to names in the filesystem (in `/var/run/screen/S-«username»/«pid».«session-name»` on my system), so it's not surprising that `/` isn't allowed, as its an invalid character to put in a file name. Presumably, NUL wouldn't be allowed either. (Also, various parts of the manpage document the sessionowner/ syntax.)